# minDistance doesn't work on 2d index

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Spring Data Mongodb and trying to do some geo queries.

My code on the Service:

```
public void addLocation(UserLocation userLocation) {
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(UserLocation.class)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(UserLocation.class);

        }
        mongoTemplate.indexOps(UserLocation.class).ensureIndex( new GeospatialIndex("location") );
        userLocation.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        mongoTemplate.insert(userLocation, COLLECTION_LOCATION);
    }
```

where location field is a double [2] array.

When I try to make the query:

```
public List<UserLocation> getUserNearLocation(Point p, double min, double max){
    NearQuery query = NearQuery.near(p).minDistance(new Distance(min, Metrics.KILOMETERS)).maxDistance(new Distance(max, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
//  NearQuery query = NearQuery.near(p).maxDistance(new Distance(max, Metrics.KILOMETERS));
    GeoResults<UserLocation> results = mongoTemplate.geoNear(query, UserLocation.class);


    List<UserLocation> all = new ArrayList<UserLocation>();
    Iterator<GeoResult<UserLocation>> iter = results.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
        GeoResult<UserLocation> temp = iter.next();
        all.add(temp.getContent());
    }

    return all;
}
```

I get:

```
WARN : org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate - Command execution of { "geoNear" : "userLocation" , "maxDistance" : 3.135711885774796E-4 , "minDistance" : 0.0 , "distanceMultiplier" : 6378.137 , "near" : [ 40.348553 , 18.179866] , "spherical" : true} failed: exception: minDistance doesn't work on 2d index
```

I am using Spring Data Mongo 1.7.0 RELEASE, because I saw this issue :https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1110 but it is resolved in release 1.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$minDistance` operator only works on a *2dsphere* index. (please see: [docs.mongodb.org/manual#minDistance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/minDistance/)). So just alter index creation to use a *2dsphere* index.

```java
template.indexOps(UserLocation.class)
  .ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("location").typed(GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE));
```

Comment: Yes I know, but how can I create a 2dsphere index in spring data mongodb?

Comment: `template.indexOps(UserLocation.class).ensureIndex( new GeospatialIndex("location").typed(GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE) );` should do the trick

Comment: Yes, it worked! if you put this info in the answer I will accept it, thanks